# Native QFileDialog: is it possible to have it not in a system language?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qfiledialog

I know that if I have a non-native (Qt-provided) `QFileDialog`, I can translate it by using `qt_<LANG>.qm` file.

Is there any way to make the native (e.g. Windows) `QFileDialog` show everything in a chosen language (rather than in a system language -- as far as I understand, this is the case)?

Comment: I do not know if it is possible, but has you ever seen a programm that has a windows file dialog in another language than system? If not I would take that as a hint that it might nit be possible.

Comment: No, it's not possible... write your own window if you absolutely need it